# How to copy all Database from Source to Destination server along with login credentials?

Tags: sql-server

My scenario is like this:

Task to accomplish: Migrate all Source server databases approx 100 to Destination server along with sql login credentials.

I tried with copy database wizard. It only worked at my local instances.
When I did same task into my network server then following error raised: 
Date        11/26/2018 11:47:16 AM
Log     Job History (CDW_DB-TESTSRV_SAMEER-DBA_SQL2017_2)

Step ID     1
Server      SAMEER-DBA\SQL2017
Job Name        CDW_DB-TESTSRV_SAMEER-DBA_SQL2017_2
Step Name       CDW_DB-TESTSRV_SAMEER-DBA_SQL2017_2_Step
Duration        00:00:01
Sql Severity    0
Sql Message ID  0
Operator Emailed
Operator Net sent
Operator Paged
Retries Attempted   0

Message
Executed as user: SAMEER-DBA\Administrator. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version 14.0.3045.24 for 64-bit  Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft. All rights reserved.    Started:  11:47:17 AM  Error: 2018-11-26 11:47:17.51     Code: 0x00000000     Source: DB-TESTSRV_SAMEER-DBA_SQL2017_Transfer Objects Task      Description: Failed to connect to server DB-TESTSRV.  StackTrace:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ConnectionManager.Connect()     at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.TransferObjectsTask.TransferObjectsTask.OpenConnection(Server& server, ServerProperty serverProp)  InnerException-->Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication.  StackTrace:    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, SqlAuthenticationProviderManager sqlAuthProviderManager)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)     at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)     at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)     at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)     at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)     at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)     at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)     at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()     at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ConnectionManager.InternalConnect(WindowsIdentity impersonatedIdentity)     at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ConnectionManager.Connect()  End Error  DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started:  11:47:17 AM  Finished: 11:47:17 AM  Elapsed:  0.484 seconds.  The package execution failed.  The step failed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like you are using wrong login to get this thing work can you try sa user? Things are not clear how you are trying to connect on both the servers. If you can read the error you will get to know that it is not able to connect to destination server and error is **The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication.**

work around for this: **Change SQL server to use both Windows and SQL Server accounts.**

Comment: logged in with sa credential for both source and destination server

Comment: Did it workout for you?

Comment: >>>logged in with sa credential <<< You was logged in with your Windows account, and your servers are not in the same domain. You should use SQL Server login and not Windows login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably achieve your goal with a few lines of Powershell code using the cmdlets provided by [dbatools](https://dbatools.io/download/), which is a free PowerShell module with over [400 SQL Server best practice, administration, development and migration commands included](https://dbatools.io/commands/).

[Migrating application databases with dbatools](https://dbatools.io/migrating-application-dbs/) provides useful examples for the tasks you want to do.

**Step 1 – Check for connections**

```
Get-DbaProcess -SqlInstance SourceServer -Database MigratingDatabase | Stop-DbaProcess
```

**Step 2 – Migrate the database(s)**

```
Copy-DbaDatabase -Source SourceServer -Destination DestinationServer -Database MigratingDatabase -BackupRestore -NetworkShare \\fileshare\
```

**Step 3 – Migrate the user logins**

```
Copy-DbaLogin -Source SourceServer -Destination DestinationServer -Login AppReadOnly, AppReadWrite, DOMAIN\AppUser
```